# Solution without DMZ that uses SFTP to access files, is this fundamentally wrong?

Tags: sftp

At this company that I am working for we are discussing the merits of have a DMZ in a production environment that interfaces with other partner networks. The platform in the production among other things downloads files over SFTP.

The platform uses Azure Data Factory SFTP connector to access files. The connection 'opens' (this is the language used by security person) for periods of time when downloading files that meet a name convention. The Azure Data Factory resource is contained within a private firewalled VNet.

Does there need to be an IP restriction lifted so that the partner machine can respond? It was described to me that the SFTP connector when specified as source 'pulls' files. Is it possible to authorize pulls only?

There are 2 issues that I think are there:

1. Scanning files for viruses (not implemented).
2. Removing IP restriction to the VNet that has Azure Data Factory in it which *could* expose other VNets in production.

Comment: You need to clarify the question a tad more. The questions that I have are: 1. What is your goal? 2. What do you mean by > The plaform in the production among other things downloads files over SFTP? 3. Technically, a connecetion has to be made and not opened, ports can be opened though 4. What kind of VNet is it? 5. By pull files you mean just download, right?